# How do I add onto a dynamic object key name other key values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I have an object that it's value changes dynamically (user unique value which I can later access it when the user comes back with the same value) so there is one object, and inside it i PATCH new user every time I need to

I tried using this code:

```
var key = userID;

var obj = {};

obj[key] = userID;
```

Which does indeed change the key to the userID (and it's value as well in this case) which is unique per user (grabbed from an API)
but how can I push key values under it?

the above result gives:

```
{"157183686647267":157183686647267}
```

however I want to have more key values under it like the example below:

```
var ids = {

"userID" : {    // the userID here should be dynamic but not 
//possible without using the method above
"userID" : userID, // will grab from here the userID
"lastTime" : currentTime, // the currentTime
"userType" : userType // the users Type
}

}
```

So I would like the final object generated to look like this:

```
var ids = {

"157183686647267" : {    

"userID" : "157183686647267", 
"lastTime" : "1571834500285",
"userType" : "VIP" 
}

}
```

(ps. using node.js)

Comment: Just assign an object instead? `obj[key] = {userID: key}`

Comment: You probably need [Shorthand and Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) Something like: `var ids = { [userID]: { userID, lastTime, userType } }` ?

Comment: @adiga Is this supported in node.js? doesn't seem to work for me:     var ids = {
    var ids = {
    [userID]: { 
      "userID" : userId, 
      "lastTime" : lastTime,
      "userType" : userType
    }

}

Comment: @Felix King - not sure I understand, could you help me with a full example according to my example?

Comment: @adiga - nevermind - it works now - so simply xD ! thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this only,

```
const ids = {
  [userID] : {
    userID,
    lastTime, 
    userType,
  }
}
```

`userID` here `[userID]` is a variable